# C Unwanted random characters being printed

Tags: c, arrays, debugging

I have written some code in C, what it does is take an input of 2 strings A, B Where A is a normal string and B is a Sub string inside B. The program will "cut" out all the appearances of the sub sting B inside the string A. For example:
 A = "asdLEONasd", B = "asd" => C(Result) = "LEON".

everything seems to be working fine except after the output stage where it prints out a few unwanted characters.

Here are 2 examples for this: (the unwanted characters are underlined with a red pen)

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqmml.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSC1C.png)

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int len1, len2;

    puts("Input a length for a");
    scanf("%d",&len1);
    // Initializing A
    char a[len1 + 1];
    puts("Input a");
    scanf("%s" ,a);

    puts("Input length for b");
    scanf("%d",&len2);
    //Initializing B
    char b[len2 + 1];
    puts("Input b");
    scanf("%s" ,b);

    int i, j , k, count1 = 0, count2;

    for(i = 0; i < len1; i++) //Loop that goes over string a
    {
        count2 = 0, k = 0;
        for(j = i; j < len2 + i; j++) //Loop that goes over a part of a (from i to i + len2)
        {
            if(a[j] == b[k])
            {
                count2++; //Counting how many characters match with the sub string B
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(count2 == len2) //If counted characters = len2 then we know that we found the Sub string B in A
        {
            count1++; //Counting each appearance of B in A
            for(j = i; j < len2 + i; j++) //Loop that marks cells that represent the sub string B in A
            {
                a[j] = '0'; //Marking cells that are the sub string b
            }
        }
    }

    if(!count1) //If count1 remained as 0 then B does not appear in A, which means the result is A
    {
        puts(a);
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;
        int len3 = len1 - count1 * len2; //Determining resulting array size
        char c[len3]; // Initializing array C
        //Filling array C accordingly
        for(i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] != '0')
            {
                c[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        puts(c);
    }
}
```

What I find most weird is when my output array has a size of 4 for example, and  it still prints the extra characters regardless the size.
I'm very curious as of why this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: ".. when my output array has a size of 4 for example, and it still prints the extra characters regardless the size." That is the basic explanation – you are misunderstanding what `puts` does. It does *not* print an array; just like any print-related functions, it merely starts printing *at* the start of that array, and continuous until it finds a `0` byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of a dumb implementation of `puts` as follows:

```
void puts(char *s)
{
  while (*s) //if the current character isn't 0
  {
    putchar(*s); //print the character
    ++s; //move to the next character
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Therefore, if the last character in your array isn't `0`, the above loop will continue until there happens to be a `0` somewhere in the memory that follows.

If you're unable to add this terminating zero (as already mentioned by Bathsheba and yourself), you could use `printf`.

When using the `printf` family of functions, you can use the `%s` specifier to format a string (such as padding and limiting it's length).

```
char x[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
//print just abc
printf("%.*s\n", 3, x);
//print just abc
printf("%.3s\n", x);
//print just bcd
printf("%.*s\n", 3, x+1);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help I actually didn't know about that the '\0' was required at the end of the string for the printf / puts, though I still don't quite understand where do these random characters come from.

Comment: @LeonKagan In C, a character array is only a _string_ if it contains a _null character_ - therefore all strings contain a _null character_ by definition - else it is not a string.  `puts(s)` and `printf("%*s", s);` require `s` point to a _string_.  `printf("%*.3s", s);` tolerates `s` as only a character array pointer.

Comment: @LeonKagan The "random characters" you're seeing are just "junk" that happens to be after the end of your array (in this case, because you put your character arrays as local variables probably the values of other local variables and, depending on how long it takes until you reach some random 0 byte somewhere, random stuff).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the array C.
Changing `char c[len3];` to `char c[len3 + 1];` and adding an initialization `c[len3] = '\0';` fixed this.

Comment: This approach has a weakness.  The central issues is that asking for the length and then the input relies on the user entering coherent text like `3` and `"abc"` and not `3` and `"ab"` or   `3` and `"abcd"`.  Robust code would cope with various user inputs by simply asking for the textual input without asking prior for its length.  Perhaps that is for later coding challenges?

Answer (score 0):

Before the third lines in the reciprocal of the program,that's right in front of this statement `puts(c)`, if you add `c[j]='\0'`, the problem you said will be solved.